# Mapreduce join: How to get the set of (item1,item2) where item1=not in data A and item2=in data A?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have two data files, where

> records of A = {item1, rating} 
>   records of B = {(item1, item2), similarity}

I'm looking to output a set where records are in something like {item1 (from A), item2 (in B but not in A), similarity, rating (item1)} form.

I have been looking for ideas and it seems like I'll probably do reduce-side joins for the datasets.. something like

```
for all item_i in B,
after map: {item_i, [(rating), (item2,sim), (item5, sim) ...]}
```

and in reduce, accumulate two hashsets representing B-A and A based on the existence of rating, and maybe get the intersections of the sets (and then output this intersection).

The problem is that I feel like this is not an optimal way of doing this since it will consume much memory during reduce stage.. This is the best way I've come up with so far. Is there more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea like this:

**Maper**:

task both `record1` and `record2` as input, output like this:

```
item1\trating 
item1\titem2,similarity
```

**reducer**:

merge the info corresponding to `items1`, this won't take much memory.

```
item1\titem2\tsimilarity\trating   #this is output1
{item1 (from A), item2 (in B), similarity, rating (item1)}
```

**UPDATE**

Just add another `MR` would solve your problem.

**Maper2**:

task both `record1` and `output1` as input, output like this:

```
item2\trating 
item2\titem1\titem2\tsimilarity\trating
```

**reducer2**:

filt the `items2` which only appear in one file.

```
item1\titem2\tsimilarity\trating
{item1 (from A), item2 (in B but not in A), similarity, rating (item1)}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm not sure in that way, I will be able to check if item2 is not in A.. but thanks for the answer!! :)